# OK to make a method generic just to pass in a System.Type?

Tags: c#, generics

Sometimes I have a function that takes a `System.Type` parameter, like:

```
public void Foo(Type type) {
    // do something with "type"
    ...
}
```

This must be called like this:

```
Foo(typeof(MyType));
```

I would like to rewrite it like this:

```
public void Foo<T>() {
    var type = typeof(T);
    // do something with "type"
    ...
}
```

That way, my callers don't have to specify the "typeof" operator every time they call my method:

```
Foo<MyType>();
```

Is this OK or is it an abuse of generic types?

Answer (score 8):

I wouldn't say it's an *abuse*. It's certainly something you can do with generics, and it sometimes makes your code cleaner. Here's the caveats:

1. While it's super easy to go from generic to `Type` it's very difficult to do the opposite. If your caller is likely to have a `Type` variable rather than calling your stuff with an explicit type... maybe reconsider.
2. It should be exceedingly rare that you work with `Type`s directly, since reflection is often the only useful thing you can do with them - and you should be avoiding reflection use. Consider if you *really* need the `Type` or if you're doing something dirty to cause that requirement in the first place.

Comment: Because of #1, I would consider having both overloads. For example, [`GetCustomAttribute()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.customattributeextensions.getcustomattribute) does just that. The generic one for convenience, the one taking `Type` for when you only have `Type`.